# Custom routing within an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

i have an Area called Members and the following registered routes in the MembersAreaRegistration file:

```
context.MapRoute(
     "Members_Profile",
     "Members/Profile/{id}",
     new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Mvc.Areas.Members.Controllers" }
     );

context.MapRoute(
     "Members_default",
     "Members/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Mvc.Areas.Members.Controllers" }
     );
```

I want to be able to map the following URLs:

```
~/Members (should map ~/Members/Home/Index )
~/Members/Profile/3 (should map ~/Members/Profile/Index/3)
```

With this route registrations everything works fine. However, I added the following URL:

```
~/Members/Profile/Add
```

and I got the error:

> "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'MyProject.Web.Mvc.Areas.Members.Controllers.ProfileController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."

I also want to have the URL

```
~/Members/Profile/Edit/3
```

What should I modify in order to have all this URLs working properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add a couple of additional routes, BEFORE the routes you have already defined.  This is because these are specific routes that you want picked before the more generic routes you already have.

```
context.MapRoute(
     "Members_Profile",
     "Members/Profile/Add",
     new { controller = "Profile", action = "Add" },
     new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Mvc.Areas.Members.Controllers" }
     );

context.MapRoute(
     "Members_Profile",
     "Members/Profile/Edit/{Id}",
     new { controller = "Profile", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Mvc.Areas.Members.Controllers" }
     );
```

Comment: I followed your advice with a little modification. Now the routes I am using are as follows (the order is important):
1. "Members/Profile/Add"
2. "Members/Profile/{id}"
3. "Members/{controller}/{action}/{id}" 

I got rid of the route for Edit, because it is covered by the last and most generic one. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  Please mark the question as answered so others can find it too.